# Is upgrading Ubuntu release with software updater the same thing as do-release-upgrade?

Tags: update-manager, do-release-upgrade

So, does software updater run do-release-upgrade in the background when upgrading to a new release or is it doing something differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Kubuntu gui updater shows me the command, which is executed. It was `do-release-upgrade -m desktop` with another argument for "show Kubuntu GUI updater"